# How do I make my water refract only underwater using Shader graph?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have made a water shader using shader graph in HDRP and I cannot figure out how to make it refract only underwater.
The node network is too big to post here as an image, but the end result can be seen in [this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqJDl.jpg)

I have outlined the wrong refractions in red.
I know that what I have to do is change the UVs so that it only takes into account the objects below the water plane. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess you are putting shader on the cubes, but better idea would be to use your own renderer. You can control what should be rendered after what etc.